# Simplicial resolutions and the homotopy fixed points spectral sequence

Tags: spectral-sequences, stable-homotopy-theory, equivariant-topology

According to [this](https://web.ma.utexas.edu/users/a.debray/lecture_notes/u17_spectral_sequences_in_equivariant.pdf) set of notes, which says (paraphrasing):

"To construct the homotopy fixed points spectral sequence, we use the fact that the bar construction gives a simplicial resolution of $(EG)_+$ which yields a cosimplicial object etc."

I believe what is meant is that we consider the sets, viewed as discrete topological spaces:
$$
B^0_+ = B^0(G,G,*)_+ \Leftarrow B^1_+ = B^1(G,G,*)  \Lleftarrow\cdots
$$
Apply $F(-,X)^G$
$$
F(B^0,X)^G_+ \Rightarrow F(B^1_+,X) \Rrightarrow_ \cdots
$$
and this **is** literally the cosimplicial object we feed into the Bousfield-Kan spectral sequence.

Is this correct, or is there something basic I'm missing?